# SQL - How to find the correct parent id by knowing the children' conditions?

Tags: c++, mysql, sql

How to find the correct `BundleId` if the input is:

```cpp
struct Cart {
    int ProductId;
    int Quantity;
};

// the input is 3 grapes and 4 oranges
std::vector<Cart> input = {
    {3, 3}, 
    {2, 4},
};
```

```sql
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
-- ---------------------------------------------------------


-- CREATE TABLE "Bundle" ---------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE `Bundle`( 
    `Id` Int( 15 ) NOT NULL,
    `Name` VarChar( 255 ) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL )
CHARACTER SET = latin1
COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci
ENGINE = InnoDB;
-- -------------------------------------------------------------


-- CREATE TABLE "BundleProduct" --------------------------------
CREATE TABLE `BundleProduct`( 
    `BundleId` Int( 15 ) NOT NULL,
    `ProductId` Int( 15 ) NOT NULL,
    `Quantity` Int( 15 ) NOT NULL )
CHARACTER SET = latin1
COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci
ENGINE = InnoDB;
-- -------------------------------------------------------------


-- CREATE TABLE "Product" --------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE `Product`( 
    `Id` Int( 15 ) NOT NULL,
    `Name` VarChar( 255 ) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL )
CHARACTER SET = latin1
COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci
ENGINE = InnoDB;
-- -------------------------------------------------------------


-- Dump data of "Bundle" -----------------------------------
BEGIN;

INSERT INTO `Bundle`(`Id`,`Name`) VALUES 
( '1', 'Buy 2 Apple Free 1 Orange' ),
( '2', '3 Grape + 4 Orange Get 1 Strawberry' );
COMMIT;
-- ---------------------------------------------------------


-- Dump data of "BundleProduct" ----------------------------
BEGIN;

INSERT INTO `BundleProduct`(`BundleId`,`ProductId`,`Quantity`) VALUES 
( '1', '1', '2' ),
( '2', '3', '3' ),
( '2', '2', '4' );
COMMIT;
-- ---------------------------------------------------------


-- Dump data of "Product" ----------------------------------
BEGIN;

INSERT INTO `Product`(`Id`,`Name`) VALUES 
( '1', 'Apple' ),
( '2', 'Orange' ),
( '3', 'Grape' ),
( '4', 'Strawberry' );
COMMIT;
-- ---------------------------------------------------------


/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
-- ---------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT BundleId
FROM BundleProduct
WHERE (ProductId, Quantity) IN ((3, 3), (2, 4))  -- source criteria pairs
GROUP BY BundleId
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2                              -- the amount of pairs
```

Comment: thanks a lot, can i ask you again? how to make it work if the `Quantity` can be >= threshold like 4 grapes

Comment: @NoorWachid Replace `WHERE IN` with a group of separate conditions similar to `WHERE (ProductId = 3 AND Quantity >= 3) OR (ProductId = 2 AND Quantity >= 4)`